# How many finger prints can be stored at a time in an IOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, fingerprint, touch-id

Does the number change with the IOS version?

Is there a way an app can read how many finger prints are defined at a time for the device?

Can we distinguish between these fingerprints? Are they stored separately or they all have the same hash code?

Answer (score 2):

You can store up to 5 fingerprints at a time. Fingerprint data not accessible by any developer (minor exceptions explained below). And they shouldn't. You can't just let anyone mess around with confidential data.

You use `LocalAuthentication` to work with TouchId. And it only lets you check (when there's an error) things like if there is no password set, if TouchId is unavailable, if the authentication failed, etc.

So, **NO**, you can't read any of the fingerprint data. And don't even try.

Comment: Is that number same for different IOS versions?  Also I understand that I cannot read how many fingerprints are stored in the device at a time.

Comment: It's the same for any iOS version (7 and up).

Answer (score 1):

TouchId API only gives you Boolean information when you authenticate your app using TouchId which is true or false. This matches the pattern fingerprint given by user with the already setup fingerprints.

Apple doesn't and never never provide such an API which will actually reveal the fingerprint setup by the user.

Max 5 fingerprints can be stored by the user.